# AOP aspects in a multi-module Maven project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

I have a multi-module Maven project and configured Spring AOP in one of my module. Unfortunately AOP only works for the project where it is. Here is my Maven config:

The parent `pom.xml`:

```xml
<parent>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<modules>
    <module>rabbitmq</module>
    <module>rss_parser</module>
</modules>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The first module (where my AOP config is):

```xml
 <groupId>com.rss.rabbitmq</groupId>
<artifactId>rabbitmq</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>rabbitmq</name>

<parent>
    <groupId>gpw.radar.rss</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <rss.parser.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</rss.parser.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rss.parser</groupId>
        <artifactId>rss-parser</artifactId>
        <version>${rss.parser.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The second module (where the AOP does not work):

```xml
<groupId>com.rss.parser</groupId>
<artifactId>rss-parser</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>rss_parser</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <rometools.version>1.7.0</rometools.version>
    <jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>2.6.1</jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>
    <jackson-databind.version>2.6.6</jackson-databind.version>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>gpw.radar.rss</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
        <artifactId>rome-fetcher</artifactId>
        <version>${rometools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-datatype-jsr310.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And finally my Spring AOP configuration from the first module:

```
@Pointcut("within(com.rss.rabbitmq.cron..*) || within(com.rss.rabbitmq.sender..*) || within(com.rss.parser..*)")
public void loggingPointcut() {
}
```

And I am using the pointcut in this aspect:

```
@Around("loggingPointcut()")
public Object logAround(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    // <<implementation>>
}
```

After some digging, I understand that it should work fine if I have myproject /jar in classpath, but in my case it does not work. The AOP for the first module, so for the `"within(com.rss.rabbitmq.cron..*) || within(com.rss.rabbitmq.sender..*)"`, works correctly but for the second project it does not.

Also I was trying to change the package name as the first parts are the same and I was thinking that it could cause the problem but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

parent dependencies are not inherited properly, use dependencyManagement.

it is more clearly explained in [documentation here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

parent - pom.xml

```xml
<parent>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<modules>
  <module>rabbitmq</module>
  <module>rss_parser</module>
</modules>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

first module - pom.xml

```xml
<groupId>com.rss.rabbitmq</groupId>
<artifactId>rabbitmq</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>rabbitmq</name>

<parent>
  <groupId>gpw.radar.rss</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <rss.parser.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</rss.parser.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.rss.parser</groupId>
    <artifactId>rss-parser</artifactId>
    <version>${rss.parser.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

second module - pom.xml

```xml
<groupId>com.rss.parser</groupId>
<artifactId>rss-parser</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>rss_parser</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
  <rometools.version>1.7.0</rometools.version>
  <jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>2.6.1</jackson-datatype-jsr310.version>
  <jackson-databind.version>2.6.6</jackson-databind.version>
</properties>

<parent>
  <groupId>gpw.radar.rss</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent-module</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.rometools</groupId>
    <artifactId>rome-fetcher</artifactId>
    <version>${rometools.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-datatype-jsr310.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson-databind.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: It did not work. Probably I am missing some spring aop concept. I made sperately projects for module1 and module2. For module2 I did the mvn install then I run mvn package for module1 but still the aop does not work for modul2.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found where was the problem. From the spring aop documentation:

> If you only need to advise the execution of operations on Spring
>   beans, then Spring AOP is the right choice. If you need to advise
>   objects not managed by the Spring container (such as domain objects
>   typically), then you will need to use AspectJ.

As my second module is not using the spring at all I should use the AspetJ instead of spring aspects.

Comment: Exactly. You should use the [AspectJ Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/) in order to compile and weave your aspects. The plugin has options to include aspects from other modules into your plain Java modules.